# Is index key enough or should I add foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, foreign-keys, inner-join

I am not sure if I should add foreign key to my table, as for now I only use index key on INNER JOINS.

Eg: I have 4 tables.

Ad > primary key **ad_id**

User > primary key **user_id**

State > primary key **state_id**

City > primary key **city_id**

On my ad table.

Each ad have a **seller_id** and a **buyer_id**, those rows inner joins to the user table on user tables row **user_id** which is a primary key in that table.

Each ad also have a **state_id** and **city_id** that inner joins to the city / state table where those rows are a primary key.

As for now I have only set those fields in my Ad table as index keys, those index keys then inner join to a primary key in another table. Should I also set those index keys in the ad table as **foreign keys**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys bring one-to-many relationships to mind.  That's not what you have here.

You should add indexes to columns that participate in WHERE clauses above and beyond your JOINs on primary keys.

Comment: Thanks, so I should use index keys on columns that are used on INNER JOINS and WHERE queries?

Comment: I'm assuming that your JOINS are already going against primary keys.  You don't need to do anything else with them.  It's non-key columns in WHERE clauses that should have indexes added.